# Ubuntu 20.04 - Nautilus does not open folders with a double click

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus

For a few weeks now, Nautilus has not been working as it should. When I open the personal folder on the desktop and then want to open other folders, a double click is not enough, I have to press the mouse button three times until the folder is open. Interestingly, when I boot my desktop from the stick, I don't have this problem. I don't have these problems on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04). ChatGPT could not help me. I have also searched in various forums. The tips are all for 18.04 or earlier versions. In the **Settings** nor in  `gnome-tewaks` is there a possibility to adjust the mouse in this respect.

Do you have a tip? Thank you very much.